# Where to start WPF Application Framework (WAF ) for beginner?

Tags: c#, wpf, waf

Can anyone suggest me some websites to learn WPF Application Framework (WAF ) for beginner ? I haved read here http://waf.codeplex.com/. But its not show up any tutorial links even Google.

Comment: Hopefully my answer helped. However, questions asking for a favorite off-site resource are generally discouraged on StackOverflow, as they tend to lead to opinion-based answers. Please feel free to ask any questions you come across as you are learning though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look around on MSDN, they have lots of good tutorials. In particular I would recommend this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

In general though, just try stuff. Create a simple application, hook it up to a simple view model, and once you get something working, start changing small pieces to make it do what you want. In my experience that is always the best way to learn a new technology!